# File upload from multiple fields using Submit button

Tags: reactjs, file-upload, react-hook-form

I have built a form using `react-hook-form` and `mui`.

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-multiple-input-fields-vdlj85

This is a 'dymanic' form generator & can have multiple `file-upload` fields. In order to get a certain look (upload icon from MUI & file name from `react-hook-form`), my implementation of the upload field is a little complex.

Nonetheless, everything is working fine and all validation for the file selected is functioning.

Current implementation is such as way that once the user selects the file, the check for size & format is done and then the upload (upload API is not in the code of the sandbox but it can be added just like the check for size & format).

However now, there is a requirement that all uploads should happen when the user clicks `SUBMIT` and not on use selecting the file.

I am not able to accomplish this part. File size & format should still happen on file selection but upload on Submit. I am not able to figure hoe to get the paths of all the selected files into a separate object from where I am upload them in loop. Can anyone guide as to hot to accomplish this?